# Combining two LINQ queries that only their return result is different

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query that is a join to a few tables like `TableA`, `TableB`, `TableC` and `TableD` and at the end I am saying `select tableA` to work with its tableA roecrds that it returned.
Then later on I have another query that its `tables, joins and where clause` is exactly the same as the first query but the only difference is that at the end I am this time saying `select tableB`

So my question is that can I combine these together so I wouldn't have to run the query two times?

```
        var query1 = (from ta in this.Context.TableA
                          join tb in this.Context.TableB on ta.Id equals tb.Id
                          join tc in blah
                          join td in blah
                          join te in blah
                          join tf in blah
                          join tg in blah
                          where (someConditionIsTrueOk)
                          select tg).ToList();


        var query2 = (from ta in this.Context.TableA
                          join tb in this.Context.TableB on ta.Id equals tb.Id
                          join tc in blah
                          join td in blah
                          join te in blah
                          join tf in blah
                          join tg in blah
                          where (someConditionIsTrueOk)
                          select te).ToList();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney updated, added sample query... use imagination powers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select multiple tables, or columns within a table, and group them together into an anonymous class which is then created on-the-fly:

```
var result = (from ta in this.Context.TableA
              join tb in this.Context.TableB on ta.Id equals tb.Id
              ...
              ...
              where (someConditionIsTrueOk)
              select new {ta, tb}).ToList();

var firstTableA = result[0].ta;
var firstTableB = result[0].tb;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which has a tg, a te and so on.

Then query just once:

```
var listOfThings = (from ta in this.Context.TableA
                          join tb in this.Context.TableB on ta.Id equals tb.Id
                          join tc in blah
                          join td in blah
                          join te in blah
                          join tf in blah
                          join tg in blah
                          where (someConditionIsTrueOk)
                          select new YourNewClass { Tg = tg, Te = te, and so on }).ToList();
```

Or as Grant said, if you don't need a structure, you can select an anonymous object:

```
var query = (from ta in this.Context.TableA
             join tb in this.Context.TableB on ta.Id equals tb.Id
             ...
             ...
             where (someConditionIsTrueOk)
             select new {tg, te}).ToList();
```